# Heroku missing last 4 migrations. Migration files do exist in Git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-migrations

Heroku is missing the last 4 migrations for a RoR app. The files exist in the git repository and are named/numbered accordingly. I tried manually forcing that version to run, but it simply can't find it. I tried this:

`heroku run rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20190328183515`

and the result was

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownMigrationVersionError: No migration with version number 20190328183515
```

Trying to redeploy from local to heroku stage does nothing since it states everything is up to date. I tried touching the files in case they weren't included in the deployed files, but looking at the git repository confirmed that's not the case.

Any ideas on what's going on here and how to get heroku to recognize that it is missing 4 migration files that still need to be processed? Resetting the database is not an option. I tried rolling back the database and running the migrations again but it stops on the migration file for 3/27/2019

Comment: Can you see the changes in db/schema.rb?If Not, then the changes are still not updated.

Comment: In my local, yes I can, in heroku no. Running this `heroku rake db:migrate:status ` in heroku vs local results in a discrepancy of 4 files. I just tried resetting the repo and redeploying. Same issue. I don't know why it's not picking up the migration file changes. I tried creating a new blank migration file to see if that would force all the other ones in, but the issue persisted.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the git repo. I just logged into bash and even though heroku claims files are up to date, I can see that none of those files are in the heroku folders. It's missing more than just the migrations

Comment: You found your answer.Just hard reset and push the files and check again with git status.This will update all new files at the repo and then you are good to go :)

Comment: The issue was actually the procfile I believe. It was running some release commands that were failing and as a result even though the files were updated, it was not using those for any of the rake tasks. I just removed that, redeployed, and that did it.

Comment: Good to see that. :)